# Character non initialised pointer in c

Tags: c, string

I am learning c programming language.

I have written a code to print only the English alphabet from the given string.

The output of this code is segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *onlyalpha(char *str) {
  char *res;
  int k = 0;
  for (int i = 0; *(str + i) != '\0'; i++) {
    if (str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90 || str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)
      res[k++] = str[i];
  }
  res[k] = '\0';
  return res;
}

int main() {
  printf("%s\n", onlyalpha("Raj12she&#khar"));
  return 0;
}
```

please help with this code.

In other code I have written `strcat2()` function, I could modify noninitialised character string, and this worked as I wanted
i.e. join the two strings.

Below is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strcat2(char *s, char *sr) {
  char *r;
  int l1, l2;
  l1 = strlen(s);
  l2 = strlen(sr);
  for (int i = 0; *(s + i) != '\0'; i++) {
    r[i] = s[i];
  }
  int i = 0;
  for (l1; *(sr + i) != '\0'; i++) {
    r[l1++] = sr[i];
  }
  r[l1]='\0';
  return r;
}

int main() {
  char str[] = "Rajashekhar", str2[] = " Dodamani";
  char *RD;
  RD = strcat(str, str2);
  puts(str);
  puts(RD);

  char *s = "Kaveri", *sr = "Dodamani";
  // s=strcat(s,sr);//s is read only ,this segmentation fault
  s = strcat2(s, sr);
  puts(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Both of these invoke *undefined behavior* for the same reason - your pointer doesn't point to any valid memory

Comment: Is this C or C++? Seems C from the code, but you tagged C++ as well

Comment: C++ and C are different language. Would you mind choosing one?

Comment: Also don't forget to terminate strings by adding `'\0'` at end of them.

Comment: Even the `strcat()` call in the second example invokes UB -- in that case because the destination array does not have sufficient capacity to add more characters.

Answer (score 1):

1. Biggest problem:

   char *res;
   //...
   res[k++] = str[i];
   //...
   res[k] = '\0';

This writes to some random place in memory. If this works in your second program it's of pure luck.

You should do something like:

```
char *strcat2(char *s, char *sr) {
  char *r;
  int l1, l2;
  l1 = strlen(s);
  l2 = strlen(sr);
  r = malloc(l1 + l2 + 1); //// <<<<<<<<<<<< make some space for the new string (+1 for '\0'
  for (int i = 0; *(s + i) != '\0'; i++) {
    r[i] = s[i];
  }
  int i = 0;
  for (l1; *(sr + i) != '\0'; i++) {
    r[l1++] = sr[i];
  }
  r[l1]='\0';
  return r;
}
```

and later maybe release the memory which is only possible if you store it's address.
This should get rid of the segfault from strcat2.

I'll suggest reading a little bit about malloc and free.

2. The libc strcat also needs you to reserve some space for it to write into:

From the MAN-page:

> char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
>
> The  strcat()  function  **appends the src string to the dest** string,
> overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and
> then adds a terminating null
> byte.  The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result.  If dest is not large enough,
> program behavior is unpredictable;

You need to reserve a larger area than your first string needs to fit your second string in there.

```
char str = "Rajashekhar", str2[] = " Dodamani";
char *s = malloc(strlen(str) + strlen(str2) + 1);
strcpy(s, str); // strcpy may also be dangerous if s is not big enough!
strcat(s, str2);
```